# DataTables data doesn't refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I fetch data and config from server via ajax (but not via DT config. I have my own logic for data fetch).
Every time I fetch data i am using this code to draw DT:

```
    var DTCfg = $.extend(config.DTConfig, {
        retrive: true,
        destroy: true,
        data: data,
        columns: columns
    });

    config.DTObj = config.table.DataTable(DTCfg);
```

Problem is that table doesn't change after first request. Even when i destroy or clear it table is rebuild by data from first request. Doing this before DT init doesn't help:

```
    config.DTObj.destroy();
    config.DTObj.clear();
    config.DTObj.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this a try

```
var dataSet = [];

if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#yourTable')) {
    $('#yourTable').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "processing": true,
        "data": dataSet
    });
} else {
    $('#yourTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "data": dataSet
    });
}
```